# Sparse Matrix - Effect and Solution

Tags: machine-learning

Can anybody explain me what are the effects on the model if we have sparse data in our dataset. And also how to deal these sparse matrices ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is really simple, just look at some online resources like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

The implementation is also really simple. For pandas this page might help you https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html

Comment: There is really not much more to it.